# Uploading Shapefile to Google Earth Engine Assets "Error: Invalid property name: No. of for."

Tags: google-earth-engine

Trying to upload a Shapefile (with files .shp, .shx, .cpg, .dbf, .prj) to my assets as a new shape file, I get the following error:
"Error: Invalid property name: No. of for.".

Can someone help me what this error means in GEE?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because you have an unsupported character in the field name. In my case there was a dot "." in one of the columns, and the import was failing.
I had to rename the field, in QGIS (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75563/renaming-attributes-fields-in-shapefile-attribute-table-using-qgis ) then the import worked fine.